# Pythonic way to find the last position in a string matching a negative regex

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation

In Python, I try to find the last position in an arbitrary string that does match a given pattern, which is specified as negative character set regex pattern. For example, with the string `uiae1iuae200`, and the pattern of *not* being a number (regex pattern in Python for this would be `[^0-9]`), I would need '8' (the last 'e' before the '200') as  result.

> What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

As it's a little tricky to quickly find method documentation and the best suited method for something in the Python docs (due to method docs being somewhere in the middle of the corresponding page, like `re.search()` in the [re page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)), the best way I quickly found myself is using `re.search()` - but the current form simply must be a suboptimal way of doing it:

```
import re
string = 'uiae1iuae200' # the string to investigate
len(string) - re.search(r'[^0-9]', string[::-1]).start()
```

I am not satisfied with this for two reasons: 
- a) I need to reverse `string` before using it with `[::-1]`, and 
- b) I also need to reverse the resulting position (subtracting it from `len(string)` because of having reversed the string before.

There needs to be better ways for this, likely even with the result of `re.search()`.

I am aware of `re.search(...).end()` over `.start()`, but `re.search()` seems to split the results into groups, for which I did not quickly find a not-cumbersome way to apply it to the last matched group. Without specifying the group, `.start()`, `.end()`, etc, seem to always match the first group, which does not have the position information about the last match. However, selecting the group seems to at first require the return value to temporarily be saved in a variable (which prevents neat one-liners), as I would need to access both the information about selecting the last group and then to select `.end()` from this group.

What's your pythonic solution to this? I would value being pythonic more than having the most optimized runtime.

**Update**

The solution should be functional also in corner cases, like `123` (no position that matches the regex), empty string, etc. It should not crash e.g. because of selecting the last index of an empty list. However, as even my ugly answer above in the question would need more than one line for this, I guess a one-liner might be impossible for this (simply because one needs to check the return value of `re.search()` or `re.finditer()` before handling it). I'll accept pythonic multi-line solutions to this answer for this reason.

Comment: last position that does 'not' or does match regex? Last `e` matches `[^0-9]` pattern.

Comment: Last position that does not match a certain pattern, like being a number. For numbers this would be  `[^0-9]`. I'll update the question.

Comment: Should `s = 'uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa'` return the index of last char before a digit aka `e` (8) or the last char aka `a` (19)?

Comment: With `uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa` it should return the last position in the string, means `19`.

Comment: "way to find last position in string that does not match regex", you actually just want to find the last position that **does match** a given regex, in this case the regex just happens to be a negative character set.

Comment: @ruohola this is correct. I ask this way to avoid having an answer that involves a regex without a negative character set (there seem to be other ways to achieve that then, which don't work for me).

Comment: @ruohola many thx for making my question more understandable. "last position that matches a negative regex" is exactly what I need :)

Comment: @geekoverdose No problem :) Feel free to check out my new answer for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it sems that you just want the last position which matches a given pattern (in this case the not a number pattern).
This is as pythonic as it gets:

```
import re

string = 'uiae1iuae200'
pattern = r'[^0-9]'

match = re.match(fr'.*({pattern})', string)
print(match.end(1) - 1 if match else None)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 8
> ```

Or the exact same as a function and with more test cases:

```
import re


def last_match(pattern, string):
    match = re.match(fr'.*({pattern})', string)
    return match.end(1) - 1 if match else None


cases = [(r'[^0-9]', 'uiae1iuae200'), (r'[^0-9]', '123a'), (r'[^0-9]', '123'), (r'[^abc]', 'abcabc1abc'), (r'[^1]', '11eea11')]

for pattern, string in cases:
    print(f'{pattern}, {string}: {last_match(pattern, string)}')
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [^0-9], uiae1iuae200: 8
> [^0-9], 123a: 3
> [^0-9], 123: None
> [^abc], abcabc1abc: 6
> [^1], 11eea11: 4
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.finditer` to extract start positions of all matches and return the last one from list. Try this Python code:

```
import re
print([m.start(0) for m in re.finditer(r'\D', 'uiae1iuae200')][-1])
```

Prints:

```
8
```

**Edit:**
For making the solution a bit more elegant to behave properly in for all kind of inputs, here is the updated code. Now the solution goes in two lines as the check has to be performed if list is empty then it will print -1 else the index value:

```
import re

arr = ['', '123', 'uiae1iuae200', 'uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa']

for s in arr:
    lst = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\D', s)]
    print(s, '-->', lst[-1] if len(lst) > 0 else None)
```

Prints the following, where if no such index is found then prints `None` instead of index:

```
 --> None
123 --> None
uiae1iuae200 --> 8
uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa --> 19
```

**Edit 2:**
As OP stated in his post, `\d` was only an example we started with, due to which I came up with a solution to work with any general regex. But, if this problem has to be really done with `\d` only, then I can give a better solution which would not require list comprehension at all and can be easily written by using a better regex to find the last occurrence of non-digit character and print its position. We can use `.*(\D)` regex to find the last occurrence of non-digit and easily print its index using following Python code:

```
import re

arr = ['', '123', 'uiae1iuae200', 'uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa']

for s in arr:
    m = re.match(r'.*(\D)', s)
    print(s, '-->', m.start(1) if m else None)
```

Prints the string and their corresponding index of non-digit char and `None` if not found any:

```
 --> None
123 --> None
uiae1iuae200 --> 8
uiae1iuae200aaaaaaaa --> 19
```

And as you can see, this code doesn't need to use any list comprehension and is better as it can just find the index by just one regex call to `match`.

But in case OP indeed meant it to be written using any general regex pattern, then my above code using comprehension will be needed. I can even write it as a function that can take the regex (like `\d` or even a complex one) as an argument and will dynamically generate a negative of passed regex and use that in the code. Let me know if this indeed is needed.

Comment: @geekoverdose: If we have to do it using `\d` as regex pattern, see my edited answer's last part to show, how it can be done much easily using just one call to `re.match` and get the index of last non-digit char without list comprehension or any such sort of thing.

Comment: I really like the insight this answer gives. However, I ended up using @ruohola 's answer as in my case two easily readable and maintainable lines are the best I can achieve. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @geekoverdose: I have no issues to what answer you accept. But if you look at the revision history, other answer has kept copying my regex and approach. It was my idea to use a greedy regex like `.*(\D)` and use `re.match` and then ruohola copied my approach, claiming as his. This isn't good. I really don't care as to what answer you accept, but just puzzled as how can someone copy answer right in front and claim as theirs.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look Pythonic because it's not a one-liner, and it uses `range(len(foo))`, but it's pretty straightforward and probably not too inefficient.

```
def last_match(pattern, string):
    for i in range(1, len(string) + 1):
        substring = string[-i:]
        if re.match(pattern, substring):
            return len(string) - i
```

The idea is to iterate over the suffixes of `string` from the shortest to the longest, and to check if it matches `pattern`.

Since we're checking from the end, we know for sure that the first substring we meet that matches the pattern is the last.

Comment: This is just not pythonic at all.

Comment: I've come up with something similar to this, but I am not satisfied with its structure. A pythonic one-liner that is easily understand- and maintainable would be preferred. If this really is one of the most pythonic ways to achieve my goal, then I feel like filing a bug report with Python for this.

Comment: @ruohola I'm interested to hear your criteria.

Comment: This is not very readable, uses the `range(len(foo))` antipattern, is quite a lot of lines etc. It's a valid solution, but when OP asked specifically for a 'pythonic' solution, I don't feel like this cuts it.

Comment: @Benj how does this reverse the string?

Comment: @Rightleg I do apologise, I forgot which slice notation was for reversing!

Comment: I think you guys are confusing what pythonic is. Zen of python: "Readability counts."

A crunched one liner doesn't mean its pythonic.

Comment: @JulianCamilleri That's why the line count was only one of the reasons I called this unpythonic.

Comment: @ruohola  wasn't pointed at you; in general, people I see, feel that the shortest the better, which is not the case.